# Converting from Spherical to Rectangular

Tags: multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates

> I need to convert $\rho \sin\phi=2\cos\theta$ in to rectangular form.

**Attempt**: I tried using those nice properties :
$$x=\rho\sin\phi\cos\theta \\y=\rho\sin\phi\sin\theta\\z=\rho\cos\phi$$ and $\rho^2=x^2+y^2+z^2$ and $\cos\phi=\frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}$. I cannot find a way to get rid of  $\rho$'s and the sines and cosines. Any hints please.

Comment: First, note that $x=\rho\sin\phi\cos\theta$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiply by $\rho\sin\phi$, and note that $\rho^2\sin^2\phi=x^2+y^2$.